# How to prevent redirect when Lightning Component Overrides the Standard New button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I overrode the Standard "New" button on the Contact object.

I have created a lightning component that uses a force:createrecord to pop a create new record screen with pre-populated values.

Is there a way to prevent the redirect to a blank page in the background because if the user hits cancel they are at a blank screen (the background is a blank blue page, not the account page where this contact related list is with the "New" button).

Otherwise is there a way to detect when the cancel button is clicked?

[image]

cmp

```
 <aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">

    <aura:handler  name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>

</aura:component>
```

js controller

```
init : function(component, event, helper) {
        alert("test");
            var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
            createRecordEvent.setParams({
                "entityApiName": "Contact",
                "defaultFieldValues": {
                    "AccountId": null,
                    "FirstName": "Hello",
                    "LastName": "World!",
                    "Title": "Advisor", 
                    "Description": "Hello World!"
                }
            });
            createRecordEvent.fire();
    }
```